# Set Combobox value to a default value depending on computers printer settings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox on a WPF application that contains all the printers attached to a computer. The printers are getting to the ComboBox correctly and I am also capturing the default printer. Now what I want to do is set the default or selected value on the ComboBox to the default printer.

I am getting the list of printers and the default with this

```
private void GetPrinterList()
{
    var server = new PrintServer();
    var queues = server.GetPrintQueues(new[] {EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Shared,
        EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections});

    string defaultPrinter = GetDefaultPrinter();
    
    Printers = new ObservableCollection<Printer>();

    foreach (var item in queues)
    {
        Printers.Add(new Printer { Name = item.FullName });
    }

    queues = server.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local });

    foreach (var item in queues)
    {
        Printers.Add(new Printer { Name = item.FullName });
    }

                
    var defPrinter = Printers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == defaultPrinter);
    if (defPrinter != null)
    {
        //NOTE Modified example after posting because @ASh
        //made aware (in comments) I had an error in code.
        CurrentDefaultPrinter = defPrinter.Name.ToString();
    }
}
```

On the XAML side I have tried binding both the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath to the CurrentDefaultPrinter but neither show the selected value in the ComboBox. What am missing to make this work?

```
<ComboBox 
    Width="150" 
    Height="35" 
    Margin="0,0,0,2"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    FontSize="18" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDefaultPrinter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}" />
```

I did find this solution that is similar to what I am trying to do but isn't close enough for me to solve my issue.

[Setting a default selected item in ComboBox in WPF MVVM application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791184/setting-a-default-selected-item-in-combobox-in-wpf-mvvm-application)

**Note** Both my code and XAML have been modified after posting because it was pointed out there was an error in my code. However, after the modification I am still not getting the ComboBox to show the default printer with updated code.

Comment: you probably shoud use `CurrentDefaultPrinter = defPrinter;` and bind only `SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDefaultPrinter}`

Comment: Oops I shouldn't have been using defaultPrinter. I didn't even notice that error until you pointed it out. I am going to modify my example to fix that now.

Comment: SelectedItem should be present in ItemsSource collection. so it should have the same type as items in that collection, not `string`: `Printer CurrentDefaultPrinter {get;set;}`. additionally it should raise propertychanged event (from INPC interface)

Comment: @ASh that fixed it. How do I mark this question answered and give you credit when you helped me in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't bind SelectedValue or SelectedValuePath, only SelectedItem:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDefaultPrinter}"
```

note that `SelectedItem` should be present in `ItemsSource` collection. so it should have the same type as items in that collection, not `string`. additionally it should raise PropertyChanged event (from INPC interface)

```
public Printer CurrentDefaultPrinter { get; set; }

CurrentDefaultPrinter = Printers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == defaultPrinter);
```